# Trying to implement Overview of Jacobian IK example within Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to implement the examples shown [here](https://medium.com/unity3danimation/overview-of-jacobian-ik-a33939639ab2).

But when running the code, and using the debug mode, there are no values returned. I am assuming that I am not using the correct rotation axis.

Extra Unity Details:

Joints variable is an array of GameObjects (consisting of 4).

Target is a singel GameObject.

The Tools.M_Populate, Tools.M_Multiply and Tools.M_Transpose. I have checked and seem to be working, when checking with debug data. They are simple codes that return float[,].

```
   private void Update()
 {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //JacobianIK();
            float angleA = Vector3.Angle(joints[0].transform.up, (joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position).normalized);
            float angleB = Vector3.Angle((joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position).normalized, (joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position).normalized);
            float angleC = Vector3.Angle((joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position).normalized, (joints[3].transform.position - joints[2].transform.position).normalized);


            Vector3 angles = new Vector3(angleA, angleB, angleC);
            JacobianIK(angles);
        }
 }


private void JacobianIK(Vector3 O) {
        int count = 0;
        Vector3 dO = Vector3.zero;
        while (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(joints[3].transform.position, target.transform.position)) > EPS && count < 100)
        {
            dO = GetDeltaOrientation();
            O += dO * step;
            // update angles
            updateLinks(new float[] { O.x, O.y, O.z });

            Debug.Log("Angles: " + O.ToString());
            count++;
        }

    }

private Vector3 GetDeltaOrientation() {


        float[,] Jt = GetJacobianTranspose();

        Vector3 V = (target.transform.position - joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position);

        //dO = Jt * V;
        float[,] dO = Tools.M_Multiply(Jt, new float[,] { { V.x }, { V.y }, { V.z  } });
        return new Vector3(dO[0, 0], dO[1, 0], dO[2, 0]);
    }

   private float[,] GetJacobianTranspose() {
            Vector3 J_A = Vector3.Cross(joints[0].transform.up, (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position));
            Vector3 J_B = Vector3.Cross((joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position), (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position));
            Vector3 J_C = Vector3.Cross((joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position), (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[2].transform.position));


        float[,] matrix = new float[3, 3];

        matrix = Tools.M_Populate(matrix, new Vector3[] { J_A, J_B, J_C });


        return Tools.M_Transpose(matrix);
    }
```

I am expecting a vector of angles to apply to each joint

Answer (score 1):

After a little trial and error, I beleave I have reached an answer. 
I was having issues with axis of rotation. Using the current code, it couldnt solve for XY plane (the same plane I had the gameobjects positioned on). I have uploaded to [GitHub upload](https://github.com/Maniacy2k/IK-Example) the current version.

To correct the code in the question I changed two key areas first from:

```
float angleA = Vector3.Angle(joints[0].transform.up, (joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position).normalized);
float angleB = Vector3.Angle((joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position).normalized, (joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position).normalized);
float angleC = Vector3.Angle((joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position).normalized, (joints[3].transform.position - joints[2].transform.position).normalized);
```

to:

```
float angleA = calculateAngle(Vector3.up, joints[1].transform.position, joints[0].transform.position);
float angleB = calculateAngle(Vector3.up, joints[2].transform.position, joints[1].transform.position);
float angleC = calculateAngle(Vector3.up, joints[3].transform.position, joints[2].transform.position);
...
}

private float calculateAngle(Vector3 axis, Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2)
{
    float value = 0f;
    value = Vector3.Angle(axis, (pos1 - pos2).normalized);
    Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(axis, (pos1 - pos2).normalized);
    if (cross.z < 0)
        value = -value;

    return value;
}
```

The second to change the code in the **GetJacobianTranspose()** method from:

```
private float[,] GetJacobianTranspose() {
    Vector3 J_A = Vector3.Cross(joints[0].transform.up, (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position));
    Vector3 J_B = Vector3.Cross((joints[1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position), (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position));
    Vector3 J_C = Vector3.Cross((joints[2].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position), (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[2].transform.position));
    ...
```

to:

```
private float[,] GetJacobianTranspose() {
    Vector3 J_A = Vector3.Cross(joints[0].transform.forward, (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[0].transform.position));
    Vector3 J_B = Vector3.Cross(joints[1].transform.forward, (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[1].transform.position));
    Vector3 J_C = Vector3.Cross(joints[2].transform.forward, (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[2].transform.position));
    ...
```

Using the joints[i].transform.forward is used to determine the axis of rotation that the links will be moving toward the target position, allowing to solve the IK for the XY plane.